# How to get number from between brackets in string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Currently I use arrays such as this one for version control of a Mysql database:

```
$pages_table = array (
    "GUID" => array (
        "type" => "CHAR(13)",
        "length" => 13,
    )
    "Number" => array (
        "type" => "TINYINT(4)",
        "length" => 4,
    )
    "Pagename" => array (
        "type" => "VARCHAR(30)",
        "length" => 30,
    )
```

It works, but I want to make it more clean, like:

```
$pages_table = array (
    "GUID" => "CHAR(13)",
    "Number" => "TINYINT(4)",
    "Pagename" => "VARCHAR(30)",
);
```

And then if I iterate over the array, I want to set $new_length (INT) to the number between the brackets of the $new_type string:

```
while ($column = key($pages_table)) {
    $new_type = current($pages_table);
    $new_length = //Get this value from $new_type;
    if ($existing_table[$column]['length'] < $new_length) {
        $modify[$column] = $new_type;
    }
    next($pages_table);
}
```

Comment: @Itay: It is about an integer number between brackets, not string. So their answer does not 100% fit my needs. Though the regex part is the same, I also did not know to use regex in the first place, as that questioner had a real regex question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
preg_match('/\(\d+\)/', $subject, $matches);
$new_length = $matches[0];
```

You could shorten the pattern if it is guaranteed that there are no other numbers in the string:

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $subject, $matches);
$new_length = $matches[0];
```

```
while ($column = key($pages_table)) {
    $new_type = current($pages_table);
    $hasLength = (preg_match('/\(\d+\)/', $new_type, $matches) == 1);

    $new_length = intval($matches[0]);
    if ($hasLength && $existing_table[$column]['length'] < $new_length) {
        $modify[$column] => $new_type;
    }
    next($pages_table);
}
```

Comment: `$subject` need to be `$new_type` then? Can't figure where `$subject` is coming from otherwise.

Comment: @Tim Sorry, I forgot to update the names. Yes, it is `$new_type`.

Comment: @Tim Your edit got rejected because it added more code. Edits are for corrections of already existing codes or of improvements of grammar/spelling. I edited the post myself a few seconds ago in order to include some ideas of your edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_length = (int) preg_replace('/\D/', '', $new_type);
```

Comment: Okay I see now. I still think the preg_match option is more readable.